# Windows Universal App: Could not load file or assembly - The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm trying out the new Windows Universal App and I can't get it working with a .net API necessary for the app. [The API in question is for a software our company uses called Moraware](http://help.moraware.com/article/380-jobtracker-api).

I can build a C# Classic Desktop Windows Form App for .Net 4.6, reference the .dll and it works without a problem.

When I write a C# Universal App, it builds fine, but when I do anything with the API like Connection.GetJob(12345), I get the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b743552344e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I tried adding System.Xml as a reference, but I get the error: A reference to System.XML.dll could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system.

I also added the Microsoft .NET Core Runtime Package for Windows, and the Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP, but nothing changed.

Any ideas on how I can get this api working with a Universal Windows App?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the referenced library is not a Portable Class Library and itselfs refers a full .Net Framework System.XML. This assembly is not available to the UWP loader or if also loaded not compatible with the .Net SDK distributed with UWP (.Net Core based).